# pass an javascript object to DOM element data atribute

Tags: jquery

if i fetch all data attributes from one DOM element which is the most effective way to pass it to another element?
example of data attributes that needs to be passed:

```
Object {avatar: "...", lname: "...", fname: "...", username: "..."}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `data` method with an object, that will set all the properties in the object as data values:

```
$('#SomeElement').data(obj);
```

You can duplicate the data from one element to another by getting all the data as an object and use that to set the data:

```
$('#SomeElement').data($('#SourceElement').data());
```

Demo:

```js
$('#div2').data($('#div1').data());
// show in Stackoverflow snippet
document.write(JSON.stringify($('#div2').data()));
```

```html
<div id="div1" data-avatar="42" data-lname="Pan" data-fname="Peter" data-username="peterpan07"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks. I tried exactly the same, but attribs didn't show up in source. Now i have find out JQuery keeps them in $cache...